# Which path do I need to put for index route to switch on parent route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The main idea uses path to go from index route to parent route  in nested route. So I'd like to see a path. `link="."`  is not good because I just go back but I need use path

I'd like that when I click on MenuItem(NavLink) then I will switch to parent route but  now
I click on

```
<MenuItem link={`./profile/${userId}`}>Profile info</MenuItem>
```

and my path equal  http://localhost:3000/profile/62e96087d8d815f327dc5125/profile/62e96087d8d815f327dc5125

but I need just http://localhost:3000/profile/62e96087d8d815f327dc5125

I have a route

```
 <Routes>
  <Route path={pageRoutes.HOME} element={<LayoutPage />}>
    <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route element={<ProtectedPage />}>
      <Route path={pageRoutes.PROFILE} element={<LayoutProfilePage />}>
        <Route index element={<ProfileInfo />} />
        <Route
          path={pageRoutes.EDIT_PANEL}
          element={<EditProfilePanel />}
        />
        <Route path={pageRoutes.ADMIN_PANEL} element={<AdminPanel />} />
        <Route path={pageRoutes.CART} element={<CartPage />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path={pageRoutes.PRODUCT} element={<ProductPage />} />
      <Route path={pageRoutes.ADMIN} element={<AdminPage />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path={pageRoutes.ABOUT} element={<AboutPage />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path={pageRoutes.NOT_FOUND} element={<NotFoundPage />} />
</Routes>
```

In `<LayoutProfilePage />` component I have

```
const LayoutProfilePage = () => {
           return (
             <ProfilePageStyled>
               <Breadcrumbs />
               <ProfileMenu />
               <Outlet />
             </ProfilePageStyled>
       );
     };
```

and in `<ProfileMenu>` I have

```
const ProfileMenu = () => {
 const userId = useSelector(userIdSelector);
 return (
<ProfileMenuStyled>
    // which path do I need to put in link that I will switch to this path pageRoutes.PROFILE
  <MenuItem link={`./profile/${userId}`}>Profile info</MenuItem>
  <MenuList>
    {userProfileRoutes.map(({ id, path, name, icon }) => (
      <MenuItem key={id} link={path} icon={icon}>
        {name}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </MenuList>
</ProfileMenuStyled>
 );
};
```

and my routes:

```
enum pageRoutes {
  HOME = "/",
  PROFILE = "profile/:userId",
  EDIT_PANEL = "editPanel",
  ADMIN_PANEL = "adminPanel",
  CART = "cart",
  PRODUCT = "product",
  ABOUT = "about",
  ADMIN = "admin",
  NOT_FOUND = "*",
}
```

Comment: Try removing the '.' dot in the path `<MenuItem link={`/profile/${userId}`}>Profile info</MenuItem>`

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the dot in the path

```
<MenuItem link={`/profile/${userId}`}>Profile info</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain you can either pass `pageRoutes.PROFILE` as the path, or `"."` to go to the parent path `"/profile"`.

Examples:

```
<MenuItem link={pageRoutes.PROFILE}>Profile info</MenuItem>
```

or

```
<MenuItem link=".">Profile info</MenuItem>
```

After some inspection though it seems like the `pageRoutes.PROFILE` value might actually be something more along the lines of `"/profile/:userId"`, and in this case if you are wanting to get to `"/profile/XYZ"` from `"/profile/ABC"` then omit the leading `"."`. Use the [generatePath](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/utils/generate-path) utility to keep the link dynamic.

```
<MenuItem link={generatePath(`/${pageRoutes.PROFILE}`, { userId })}>
  Profile info
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: `link=".">` is true. But ` link={`${pageRoutes.PROFILE}/${userId}`}` because `pageRoutes.PROFILE= profile/:userId` and ` ../${userId}` are false

Comment: @RadomirRadionov Yeah, I was thinking about that afterwards and was in the process of refining my answer. I didn't see that you'd actually added the `PROFILE` path value, which confirmed why your route/link felt "weird" if it wasn't a 2-path-segment value. The link needs both segments.

Comment: The main idea uses path to go from index route to parent route  in nested route. So I'd like to see a path. `link="."`  is not good because I just go back but I need use path

Comment: @RadomirRadionov "." is the path you'd use to get back to the index route path (*it matches the parent `Route` component's path*) if it was only a single path segment, but since the parent path is a compound path *with* a parameter, yes, "." alone isn't sufficient. The link needs to be fully qualified. Please see the updated second half of my answer.

Comment: For example my path equals  http://localhost:3000/profile/blablabla then I go to http://localhost:3000/profile/blablabla/adminPanel  and then when I click on ```<MenuItem link={`./profile/${userId}`}>Profile info</MenuItem>``` I will switch to http://localhost:3000/profile/blablabla

Comment: @RadomirRadionov Ok, what am I misunderstanding here? ```link={`./profile/${userId}`}``` is the link path that it seems like you are saying isn't working as expected. It will link relative to the current path of the parent route, i.e. from `pageRoutes.PROFILE` rendering `LayoutProfilePage`, then `ProfileMenu`, and ultimately the `MenuItem` with that `link` prop value. Are you ***not*** wanting the link to get you back to `pageRoutes.PROFILE` with a specific `userId` value?

Comment: Yes, I'd like go back to pageRoutes.PROFILE equals profile/:userId.

Comment: @RadomirRadionov ```link={generatePath(`/${pageRoutes.PROFILE}`, { userId })}``` should generate a link path value for that path. Or you can edit the `PROFILE` value to include the leading `"/"` so it's an absolute path, i.e. `PROFILE = "/profile/:userId"`.

Comment: It has the same result `http://localhost:3000/profile/someId/profile/someId`. I have updated my description  and now you can  see all my route, mb it's important.

Comment: @RadomirRadionov It seems you are still using a relative path instead of an absolute path. Note the leading `"/"` at the beginning of the path.

Comment: Yes, it is true, well done.